# Running Total with cap

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

Here's a sample of data for an invoice report witha  50% commission and $50 cap.  I'm using SQL Server 2008.  I think what I need is a running total of the cap column to produce the results I need.
Here is some sample data:

```
account|amount|transdate          |commission|cap
123456 |50    |2017-01-01 00:00:00|25        |25
123456 |50    |2017-02-02 00:00:00|25        |25
123456 |100   |2017-03-03 00:00:00|50        |50
```

This is what I'd like to see:

```
account|amount|transdate          |commission|cap|running_total
123456 |50    |2017-01-01 00:00:00|25        |25 |25
123456 |50    |2017-02-02 00:00:00|25        |25 |50
123456 |100   |2017-03-03 00:00:00|50        |50 |0
```

So on 2/2/17 I've hit my cap of $50 and on 3/3/17 I can no long collect on this account so the amount would be 0.

[Here's an demo of my data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/672000/invoice)

```
select account,
amount,
transdate,
coalesce(amount*.5, 0) as commission,
(case when coalesce(amount*.5, 0)>=50 then 50 else coalesce(amount*.5, 0) end) as cap
from #invoice
```

Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use a correlated subquery to compute the running total.  I do this calculation in a CTE below, and I report that running total in the final output provided the total is less than the cap, otherwise zero is reported as the total.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        account,
        amount,
        transdate,
        COALESCE(amount*0.5, 0) AS commission,
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(amount*0.5, 0) >= 50
             THEN 50 ELSE COALESCE(amount*0.5, 0) END AS cap
    FROM #invoice
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
        (SELECT SUM(t2.cap) FROM cte1 t2
           WHERE t2.transdate <= t1.transdate) AS running_total
    FROM cte1 t1
)
SELECT
    t.account,
    t.amount,
    t.transdate,
    t.commission,
    t.cap,
    CASE WHEN t.running_total > 50 THEN 0 ELSE t.running_total END AS running_total
FROM cte2 t
```

Comment: how can I use t.cap for this?
(case when coalesce(amount*.5, 0)>=50 then 50 else coalesce(amount*.5, 0) end) as cap

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted a running total of the cap or the commission.  I updated my query to use the cap instead.  Your comment doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I'm creating the cap column in the query so If I select t.cap it tells me invalid column.

Comment: I would suggest trying my query and see where it leads you.  You are not being clear now with what you need.

Comment: For the moment I'm just looking for a running total of the cap column.

Comment: Really appreciate the help but I'm getting an error on the second with statement.  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Comment: @Nick Sorry, remove the second `WITH`, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: @Nick No need for formal thanks here on Stack Overflow.  People help each other out :-)